# как сделать когда заходишь на свою страницу меню вход изменяется на пользователя

Tags: php, html

чтение и проверка из бд имя пользователя и пароли

```
 <?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lesson');
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $user_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['username']));
            $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));
            if(!empty($user_username) && !empty($user_password)) {
                $query = "SELECT `user_id` , `username` FROM `signup` WHERE username = '$user_username' AND password = SHA('$user_password')";
                $data = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
                    setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
                    setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60*60*24*30));
                    $home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                    header('Location: '. $home_url);
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Извините, вы должны ввести правильные имя пользователя и пароль';
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Извините вы должны заполнить поля правильно';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

меню входа пример скрин

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BfJm/18seN2SHo

```
             <li><a href="#">вход</a></li>
```

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2XdN/12wjv7rHA 
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5kiX/HqV5oiEqq

```
                    <a href="#">User<?php echo $_COOKIE['username']?></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Личный кабинет</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">выход</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: Я приду на ваш сайт. Посмотрю на имя админа и его id. Запишу их себе в куки браузера. Я админ! И ни какого волшебства :)

Comment: В куки писать стоит id сессии, а остальные данные хранить там)

Comment: @СашаБоричевский, в куках можно хранить все что угодно, а не только id сессии. Главное правильный подход.

Comment: Я про конкретно данный случай. Можно и хэш данных юзера хранить для сравнения на сервере. Но явно не так, как у автора)

Comment: 1. Используйте стандартный хранильщик картинок ruSO. 2. Во время авторизации/идентификации пользователя меняйте часть кода с проверкой на то, явялется ли пользователь валидным. 3. В куках лучше хранить идентификатор сессии, как подсказали выше